# Apache Hive: take one line from each group

Tags: sql, hive

I have a apache Hive table like this:

```
id          llvc    lp
2428766324  P005    P048
2428766324  P005    P024
2428766324  P005    NULL
2429788401  P005    P024
2429788401  P005    NULL
2429788401  P005    P048
2457843473  P005    P024
2457843473  P005    P048
2457843473  P005    NULL
2457872560  P005    NULL
2457872560  P005    P048
2457872560  P005    P024
```

for each id, I have one/multiple ligns and I would like to take one line each id following the condition like this:

for each group of id

```
If number of line = 1, take this line    
if number of line > 1, take the line where llvc = lp    
if number of line > 1, and no llvc == lp, take the line where lp = null
```

and abandon other lines in the group.

for example:

```
id          llvc    lp     
2428766324  P005    P048      
2428766324  P005    P024      
2428766324  P005    NULL
```

I would like to take **2428766324  P005    NULL**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by (case when llvc = lp then 1 
                                               when lp is null then 2
                                               else 3
                                          end)
                                ) as seqnum
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```